# CakePHP: Error Saving Data

Tags: php, cakephp

So I'm having troubles saving my data in CakePHP.

If I upload an image (meaning ['PictureForm']['file']['name'] exists), everything works fine and the data is saved. However, if ['PictureForm']['file']['name'] is null, and ['PictureForm']['url'] exists, then the image is correctly saved on disk, but then $this->PictureForm->save($this->data) fails.

Anyone see anything blatantly wrong with my code?

```
if (isset($this->data['PictureForm'])) {
                            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////DEV
                            if(!$this->data['PictureForm']['file']['name']) {
                                    if (!$this->data['PictureForm']['url']) {
                                            $this->Session->setFlash('Error: no image URL or file given!');
                                            $this->redirect(array('action' => '/'));
                                    } else {
                                            $fileExtension = getExtension($this->data['PictureForm']['url']);
                                            $this->request->data['PictureForm']['filename'] = randFilename() . "." . $fileExtension;
                                            file_put_contents('files/picture/' . $this->data['PictureForm']['filename'], file_get_contents($this->data['PictureForm']['url']));
                                    }
                            } else { //file was uploaded
                                    $fileExtension = getExtension($this->data['PictureForm']['file']['name']);
                                    if (!$fileExtension) {
                                            $this->Session->setFlash('Error: no file extension!');
                                            $this->redirect(array('action' => '/'));
                                    }
                                    $this->request->data['PictureForm']['filename'] = randFilename() . "." . $fileExtension;
                                    move_uploaded_file($this->data['PictureForm']['file']['tmp_name'], "files/picture/" . $this->data['PictureForm']['filename']);
                            }
                            $this->request->data = Sanitize::clean($this->request->data, array('encode' => false));
                            if ($this->PictureForm->save($this->data)) {
                                    resizeUpload($this->data['PictureForm']['filename']);
                                    $this->Session->setFlash('Picture <a href="/spootur/media/p/' . $this->data['PictureForm']['filename'] . '">saved</a>');
                                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'p/' . $this->data['PictureForm']['filename']));
                            } else {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash('Error: could not save to db' . $this->data['PictureForm']['filename']);
                                    $this->redirect(array('action' => '/'));
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Paste your code into the question directly and do not link off site. This makes it easier to answer and for people who come along later to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the save fails, in the else block, instead of redirecting try to view the validation errors:

```
if ($this->PictureForm->save($this->data)) {
    // code
} else{
    debug($this->PictureForm->validationErrors);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I was never sure how to use debug() so that'll definitely come in handy.